# Bash regex gotcha

Tags: regex, bash

I have a small problem I really can't understand :

`bash -c 'if [[ "hello" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,\}\\.$ ]] ; then echo "OK" ; else echo "KO" ; fi`

I think this should give me KO and it gives me OK...
I would like to match things with at least 1 character and ending with a dot...

I finally noticed that it works with bash version 4.1.5 and not with version 3.2.25

How should I proceed with this version ?

EDIT :

I found a workaround that works, but I don't know why I had to put the escaped dot between brackets:

```
bash -c 'if [[ "hello" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[\.]$ ]] ; then echo "OK" ; else echo "KO" ; fi'
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not escape the dot, so it is used as a wildcard and matches any character. Replace the `.` with `\.` Also, instead of `{1,}`, use `+`, because they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I did escape the dot, but it doesn't show in here (corrected now with double backslash...) Also, bash regexp doesn't accept + as a modifier...

Comment: @Lapin-Blanc the way it is now it works: http://i54.tinypic.com/2l9s561.png (used copy-paste from the question)

Comment: I guess you tried with a more recent version of bash, i'm on Centos 5.6 and ... http://i53.tinypic.com/21jd2ew.png :-)

Answer (score 1):

`.` is special in regular expressions ("match any characters").  Escape it as `\.`