# Performing if statement validation using regex (with plus sign) to catch any file extension string

Tags: regex, bash, validation, if-statement

I have been working on a bash scripts which takes a single parameter as input from the user.

I have to verify that this input has (at least) a file extension suffix [ex: '.com', '.ca', etc] AND that it doesn't have an empty name before that suffix.

I have given multiple tries at trying to set up regex validation and have come up with this regex validation statement (where $1 is what the user input): `if [[ $1 =~ ^.+\.[A-z0-9]+$ ]]`.

I thought that this string would be able to match a string starting with at least 1 character, followed by a literal dot ('.') and finally catching at least one alphabet or number character.

Here's the full code on validating user input for anyone curious.

```
domainName="";
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        if [[ $1 =~ ^.+\.[A-z0-9]+$ ]]; then
            domainName=$1;
            printf "The domain name is: \"%s\"\n" $domainName;
        else
            printf "The domain name needs at least a suffix (ex: '.com', '.ca', etc)\n";
        fi
    elif [ $# -le 0 ]; then
        printf "You need to give me a domain name to set up!\n";
        exit 1;
    else
        printf "You cannot have more than 1 domain set up at a time!\n";
        exit 1;
    fi
```

If anyone has any ideas on what is happening and how I could fix this, please share your knowledge :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is happening?

Comment: Replace `[A-z0-9]` by `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: Which version of bash are you using?  You may be running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6485767/135978)

Comment: I kept having my "The domain name needs a name AND a suffix (ex: '.com', '.ca', etc)" error. @stribizhev

Comment: Yeah, that worked @Cyrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `A-z` in your character class `[A-z0-9]` which matched many more characters between `A` and `z` in ASCII table such as: `[`, `\`, `]` etc.

Use this:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^.+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$ ]]
```

Or even better:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^.+\.[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]
```