# bash function ignoring dot for git clone command

Tags: git, bash, scripting, bash-function

I am wrestling with a bash function that will not clone to current directory, it is making a project folder:

`cloneproject() { git clone git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/$1.git . ;}`

I have the dot at the end, before semicolon, but running this within a directory named 'bookwormbuddy' makes it add a new project folder as if you ran clone without a dot:

```
me@pc:~/projects/bookwormbuddy$ cloneproject bookwormbuddy
Cloning into 'bookwormbuddy'...
```

Yet when I run the same command from terminal, it works as I'm used to:

```
me@pc:~/projects/bookwormbuddy$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/new_bookmarks.git .
Cloning into '.'...
```

I need this as I name projects different in storage for reasons. How can I make ubuntu respect the dot?
Thank you

Comment: I hadn't, and that worked: `cloneproject() { git clone git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/$1.git \. ;}`. Do you know what bash thought the dot was? Did it think it was a regex? You can answer if you want credit, thanks

Comment: Yup.  Look at [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485767/bash-regex-gotcha) for confirmation.  Check that it still runs correctly from the terminal.

Comment: It worked with one backslash

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That makes absolutely no sense, unless you want to clone into the directory named `\.`. @codyc4321 Note how the command that worked for you isn't want Tim suggested (he suggested `\\.`). And your `\.` is the same as `.`, because dot doesn't need quoting. Where are you defining the function?

Comment: Well, Tim knew what I wanted to do. I am trying to say "clone this git thing into this directory, named '.' for convenience". The dot did need quoting because as it was before, it got ignored and did not clone to current directory (.) but cloned as normal, in a new dir named after the project

Comment: this is in /home/me/.bashrc

Comment: Please show us the output of `type cloneproject`. (As I commented above and in the answer below, `.` shouldn't need quoting, so there's a problem somewhere else.)

Comment: Continuing discussion from the answer below: if you switched to the new version, you'll see `type cloneproject` prints exactly the same output, meaning that the two function definitions are just the same. Now, you might want to run `set -x` in your command line to see what's really getting executed, but I doubt you'll get any insight from there.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Can you think of any reason why the context in which the function is running treats `.` as a special character (and therefore escaping it has a special meaning) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No. As I said, `set -x`, and you'll see that it isn't treated as anything special. I bet the problem is with `git`, although I cannot reproduce in any setting. Ubuntu or not, same name or not, whatever. It just works, and there's no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen By the way, there's even more proof that dot isn't treated as anything special: the OP even mentioned that if he/she ran the command directly on the command line, with unquoted `.`, if worked...

Comment: @4ae1e1 Exactly.  This is why I agree that the `git` command is doing something here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That seems rather unlikely too. Because in the end the function should execute exactly the same command as the one directly executed on the command line (unless OP has some weird `IFS`, in which case he/she should get error messages). This is weird, and there's nothing we can do in this pursuit if OP doesn't want to pursue. Anyway, sorry about some of my stronger words earlier, but I do detest the attitude of leaving an answer unattended as soon as it's accepted, and taking offense in other's objections.

Comment: You are leaving too many comments IMO.  You got your point across a long time ago :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the dot to tell the Bash *not* to treat it as part of a regular expression:

```
cloneproject() { git clone git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/$1.git \. ;}
```

As [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485767/bash-regex-gotcha) discusses, Bash will treat a single dot as meaning "any character."

Comment: they've got a 5 minute cooldown period to accept...is this buying a gun? ;)

Comment: LOL not sure.  For future reference, you should always keep escaping characters in the back of your head.  This problem pops up in bash, regex, Java, Perl, and even SQL.

Comment: Ya, it seems like I get burned 1000 times a year not escaping something, and I never learn :)

Comment: This is just wrong (wrong in the sense that no improvement whatsoever). I don't know why the original version doesn't work (it should work, I even tested), but this is exactly equivalent to the original. This is NOT a regex setting, and `.` is not a wildcard (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion). Please don't quote random things from different settings.

Comment: @codyc4321 Please don't take the advice of always quoting the dot in bash, because that's just ridiculous. Unless I'm proven wrong later.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I was giving general advice of escaping characters which may have a special meaning, that's all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Dot has no special meaning in bash, outside a regex, or as a shell builtin (`source`). None apply here.

Comment: I'd love to learn more, but this answer immediately solved my problem on this machine. I'm using ubuntu. If the reason it fixed it is different, I'd love to know why, but it worked

Comment: By the way, dot has another slightly special meaning: `*` won't match a dot at the beginning of a filename in filename generation. Still, that has nothing to do with the situation at hand.

Comment: @codyc4321 If you want to find out why, the first step is to switch back to the version that did not work, and do `type cloneproject`, as I commented above.

Comment: `cloneproject is a function
cloneproject () 
{ 
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/$1.git .
}`

Comment: Would you all mind not making a mess on my answer?  Thanks.

Comment: He actually does have a point, the command works the old way when the folder I'm in matches the project name (autohelper and autohelper on bitbucket), but did not work when the names differed (bookwormbuddy vs new_bookmarks_tracker). Now I'm curious but it's getting late and the answer works for all use cases..

Comment: If commenting on a potentially wrong answer (and the reference definitely makes no sense, and the extraordinary claim `Bash will treat a single dot as meaning "any character."` is just hilarious, even if the answer has some value in some sense) to find out the real cause is making a mess, then sure. And you didn't address any of my legit concerns (you attitude seems to be harvest points and leave, seeing as you drew a reference that made no sense, then pressed for acception and upvote from me). Let's move the discussion to below the post.

Comment: I don't know how to do that